# CakePHP 1.3: Speeding up ACL-enabled application load time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, acl

All,

What is the best practice/approach I should take to speed up my application developed using CakePHP. I have been doing a bunch of testing by checking my `echo $this->element('sql_dump');` and improving on my `$find` operations?

1. I cache all my `$this->element()`
2. I am working on limiting my find operations to only return what I need
3. Using thumbnails where possible

The main problem I've noticed is the ACL calls

1. For instance, 1 of my pages takes about 3334 ms to load and 3320 ms is due to my ACL checks according to `sqldump`.

What else can I do to improve this specific issue and anything else in general.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Cache the ACL checks. Read them into the memory and don't query them unless you know that they changed. That's really the only option I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I've researched and found some components/tutorials on how to adopt this method and will try it later. I will post back with the results... Thanks http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/macduy/2010/01/05/acl-caching-using-session